# The jquery script function is not triggering in _layout.cshtml page while child page is loaded in ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I solicit your valuable input to resolve an issue.

**Context**: My application is having asp.net core MVC as tech stack. I have put client-side sorting and various functionalities in jquery. To make those applicable to all pages, I put those functions in _layout.cshtml page. At the time of page load, it was running fine. But when a search result(throuh ajax) populates result set in underlying modules. The jquery functions in _layout pages is not calling.

The code sample in _layout.cshtml page looks like as follows

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        // Use jQuery noConflict to avoid conflicts
        $.noConflict();

        // Make table columns resizable
        $("#mytable th").resizable({
            handles: "e", // Only allow resizing from the right edge
            minWidth: 50, // Minimum column width
            
        });
    });
</script>
```

The mytable is id of the table that contains search result in each .cshtml page. Hence, if I have N number of .cshtml pages which are having N number of mytable and one _layout.cshtml. To make those client side functions generic I put those in _layout page.

The code sample for populating the mytable in each page is different but for an example it goes like this

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btnProjects', function () {
   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Project/GetProjects?Factoryid=' + fId,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $('.table').html(data); 
                getPersistentColumn();
            }.....
    })
```

**Problem statement:**
The below code is not responding in _lauout.cshtml page inside  jQuery(document).ready  while search result is populated through ajax

```
$("#fixTable th").resizable({handles: "e", minWidth: 50, // Minimum column width});
```

Thanks and regards
Nilanjan Saha

Comment: I'm not sure that you are providing sufficient information as to how your system works, but I would personally start by checking the console for any errors, then making sure that your tables aren't getting deleted by your ajax request. If you're still having issues after that, is your "#fixTable" supposed to be the same as "#mytable"?

Comment: What does "below code is not responding" mean? Is anything happening (or not happening) on the screen? Are you seeing errors in the console? Try describing your expected behavior first, then your actual behavior so we can fully understand your problem.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for showing interest on this. I have checked the console and not found any error. table is not getting deleted. #fixTable= #myTable.

Comment: @JuanR Thanks for your time. Sorry for not making the stuff clear. Let me try now. There are two events. 1. Page_Load here all js functions inscribed in _layout.cshtml and  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {.... is triggering but 2. when after the page load, the underlying table is populated by ajax, the functions within (_layout page) document).ready(function ($) {.... is not accessible. There is no error in the console. It seems after the partial loading of the page, I am not having expected behavior.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly instead of adding details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this line of code targets the container for table `#mytable`:

```
$('.table').html(data);
```

And that `data` contains the HTML for table `#mytable`...

You are wiping out the existing table so you need to make the **new header cells** resizable once you recreate it with the contents from `data`. Call the code to do so again, right after you have replaced the HTML:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnProjects', function () {
   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Project/GetProjects?Factoryid=' + fId,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $('.table').html(data);

                // Make table columns resizable
                $("#mytable th").resizable({
                            handles: "e", // Only allow resizing from the right edge
                            minWidth: 50, // Minimum column width
                            
                        });
                 
                getPersistentColumn();
            }.....
    })
```

Comment: Thanks again for your interest. It is not working, unfortunately. I would like to add a point that might help. In the  $('.table').html(data), data contains a partial view. I mean the call   url: '/Project/GetProjects?Factoryid=' + fId,  returns partial view as return PartialView("_ProjectList", lvm);  after the successful ajax call, the content of the partial view, _projectlist is rendered in the main page.

Comment: @NilanjanSaha so why don't you share the partial view's HTML? It's hard to help when you don't provide enough information.

Comment: The code for partial view is 
"@model IEnumerable<viewmodel>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Project&nbsp;Id</th>
        <th>Project&nbsp;Name</th>        
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ProjectData.ProjectId</td>
                <td>@item.ProjectData.ProjectName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <tr>
            <td>No records found...</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>"

Comment: Please update your QUESTION. Don't place code in comments. Also, please add the content of the element that contains the child element with class `.table`.